# ASP.NET MVC Bundle each file seperate in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How render each bundled file separate in debug mode?
I want to have rendered css and js file separate in my view, because it is hard to debug javascript files when all files are bundled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create simple BundleHelper class.
After that in your *.cshtml file yo can use

> @BundleHelper.RenderScripts("~/bundles/js")
>
> @BundleHelper.RenderStyles("~/bundles/style")

```
 public class BundleHelper
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetOriginalFilePaths(string bundlePath)
    {
        var resolver = new BundleResolver(BundleTable.Bundles);
        IEnumerable<string> scriptPaths = resolver.GetBundleContents(bundlePath).ToList();
        return scriptPaths;
    }
    public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(string bundlePath )
    {
        if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations) return Scripts.Render(bundlePath);
        var scriptPaths = GetOriginalFilePaths(bundlePath);
        return Scripts.Render(scriptPaths.ToArray());
    }
    public static IHtmlString RenderStyles(string bundlePath)
    {

        if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations) return Styles.Render(bundlePath);
        var stylePaths = GetOriginalFilePaths(bundlePath);
        return Styles.Render(stylePaths.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In production it will work as you want and in development will work like as you haven't used bundling.